# redux-form-material-ui | SelectField | custom onChange prevents to show chosen value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

I use `redux-form` and `redux-form-material-ui` to create some simple form. Values in `subdepartment` select depend on value chosen in `department` select. So I created a callback function triggered onChange of `department` select. Getting data for `subdepartment` select works, but the value chosen `department` select does not appear anymore.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import { SelectField } from 'redux-form-material-ui';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

<Field
  name={name}
  component={SelectField}
  hintText={label}
  floatingLabelText={label}
  onChange={callback}
>
  {this.renderOptions(options)}
</Field>
```

The callback:

```
searchSubdepartments: departmentId => dispatch(searchSubdepartments(departmentId))
```

Comment: Did you check your store state before and after dispatching searchSubdepartments? There's probably something resetting the state of the department field. One lovely thing about redux is it should be easy enough to debug - find exactly that one piece of code that resets (clears) the department field value.

Comment: Yep. What @WTK said.

Comment: @WTK I didn't change my store, just added custom onChange to component. Without custom `onChange` I can see chosen value of `department` with custom `onChange` this value never appears